# Liferay Portlet Log4j Properties File Configuration

Tags: log4j, liferay

I want to configure my Liferay portlet project with own log4j configurations.I have followed following article and it is working fine for me.

https://web.liferay.com/web/brett.swaim/blog/-/blogs/using-log4j-to-ensure-each-portlet-has-it-s-own-log-file

Now I need to use log4j.properties file instated of log4j.xml file.So I have removed log4j.xml and put a sample log4j.properties file.After putting log4j.properties file, portlet project does not identify the log4j configurations.

My Liferay version is Liferay 6.2 CE GA5.

Sample log4j.properties file is,

```
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR,console

#Console Appender 
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=[%5p] [%t %d{hh:mm:ss}] (%F:%M:%L) %m%n

#Custom assignments
log4j.logger.controller=DEBUG,console
log4j.logger.service=DEBUG,console
log4j.logger.dao=DEBUG,console

#Disable additivity
log4j.additivity.controller=false
log4j.additivity.service=false
log4j.additivity.dao=false
```

Can anybody help me resolve this issue?

Comment: At which location you have kept this properties file in your project?

Comment: I have put it in src/main/java folder

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found the fix.Need to define the log4j properties file path in the web.xml.I have placed my log4j.properties file in the WEB-INF folder.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/log4j.properties</param-value>
</context-param>
```